# How can I evaluate elisp stored in an emacs register?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The motivation for this is as follows:
I have various files bound to registers. This allows me to jump to things like my 
xmonad config by running `C-x r j H` or my .emacs file with `C-x r j E`.

I'd like to be able to jump to my `run-haskell` buffer with `C-x r j H`. However, running `C-x r j` runs the `jump-to-register` function, so I can't just bind `C-x r j H`, afaik.

The workaround that seems easiest to me is evaluating elisp stored in a register, and hence storing `(run-haskell)` in register `H`.

But there seems to be nothing built in for evaluating elisp in registers, which makes me thing I'm approaching the problem incorrectly.

How can I solve this problem? I'm aware that this could fall in to the scope of superuser style question, but I posted here because I assumed the solution lies in writing elisp.

Comment: I think the task would be a lot easier if it didn't involve twisting the right arm of `jump-to-register` until it stops being `jump-to-register`. Could you consider accepting a different keystroke for this? Otherwise, you could bind `C-x r j` to a wrapper which invokes `jump-to-register` for all suffixes except one, but that gets awfully hackish ...

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking. The thing is, jump-to-register seems to do different things dependent on what's in a register. File name => open file; Window config => load window config; frame config => load frame config, so I was hoping to add some dispatch for buffer name

Comment: Having taken a look at register.el, it seems that it just does a big case statement on the contents of the register, poking the register contents to see its type. Can I extend this case statement at run time?

Comment: Not easily, no, other than by copy-pasting the definition and overriding it.  I'd suggest taking the advice route.

Comment: If you use [haskell-mode](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode), you can easily switch to inferior process buffer with `C-c C-z`. That might not be your case.

Comment: @m2ym I'm not using haskell-mode, I just like having the buffer open for fiddling with stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jump-to-register` does not support this directly, but you can easily extend it:

```
(defadvice jump-to-register (around jump-to-buffer-maybe
                                     (register &optional delete)
                                     activate compile)
  (let ((r (get-register register)))
    (if (bufferp r)
        (switch-to-buffer r)
      ad-do-it) ))
```

In order for this to work, the register you pick needs to contain a buffer object.  As a convenience, you might also want to define a function for putting a buffer object in a register:

```
(defun buffer-to-register (buf reg)
  (interactive "bBuffer: \ncRegister: ")
  (set-register reg (get-buffer buf)) )
```

If you really genuinely want to `eval` a register instead of `switch-to-buffer`, the modification should be trivial.  It's not clear to me how exactly to put in a reasonable safeguard in order to not execute any random piece of text, but if you restict yourself to, say, interactive commands, it should not even be too unsafe.

Comment: I'm not too fussed about being to evaluate registers. After all, that's what variables / functiond are for.

Comment: Something like this then?  `(defadvice jump-to-register (around jump-to-buffer-maybe (register &optional delete)  activate compile) (let ((r (get-register register))) (if (functionp r) (funcall r) ad-do-it) ))`